# Do I need a Service1.cs in my windows service project?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, service

Or can I call it anything I want, like Main.cs etc

Comment: Are you sure you're ready for writing a Windows service? - I'm teasing. You can call it whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't. It's just a default name. Feel free to rename it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the class is not important, as a regular C# application. What it is important is that is has to have a static Main() method.